# Custom directive in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Why this custom directive in angular js not working for me.I am only getting the user: but not getting the names of the user which I passed in the userinfo custom directive tag

**user_directive_index.html file:**

```
<html ng-app='app' >
<head>
</head>
<title>
User Directive
</title>
<body >

<div>
<div ng-model='firstcontroller'>
<userinfo user="Raj"></userinfo>
</br>
<userinfo user="Sudhir"></userinfo>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='app.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**App.js file**:

```
var app1=angular.module('app',[]);
app1.controller('firstcontroller',function($scope){
$scope.Raj={};
$scope.Raj.firstname='Rajeshwar';
$scope.Raj.lastname='Bose';
$scope.Sudhir={};
$scope.Sudhir.firstname='Sudhir';
$scope.Sudhir.lastname='Ranjan';

});

app1.directive('userinfo',function(){
var directive={};

directive.restrict='E';
directive.template='User:{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}';

directive.scope={
user:"= user"
};

return directive;
});
```

I got this code from: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change directive [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) here

```
<div ng-model='firstcontroller'>
        ^^^^^
```

To [`ngController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

```
<div ng-controller='firstcontroller'>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude....can I have your email id..so that I can put my doubts directly over there.You seem to be lot experienced in this framework.And  I am really in urgent need of some guide to help me out in Angular JS.

Comment: @Rajeshwar If this answer helps you and it solved your problem, please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)